# Is there a term describing two poems that start simultaneously or in succession?

Tags: formatting, academic-writing, poetry, text-analysis

I am studying a poem called *Unbearable Weight of Staying* by Warsan Shire. It includes regular type and then indented, italicised type e.g

> I don't know when love became elusive.
> *My mother's laughter in a dark room*

The remainder of the poem follows this form for another two stanzas, presenting two seemingly unrelated narratives and themes (of course can be able to argue this point and I intend to do so in my analysis, but I digress) so I read the regular type as if it were one poem and the italicised type as if another.

Is there a term for this, **the reader/speaking of two quasi-simultaneous poetry**?

Comment: Look to song duets and especially liturgy for words describing this 2-voice structure, not 'text formatting' and 'poetry'.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would count as a duet, or possibly polyphony. What you describe isn't really understandable except as a musical/read out loud form of poetry. Though, a duet is typically used to describe when two voices sing or speak in harmony.

It could also simply be "Layering."